# Deployed REST API always giving 500 error

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-webapi, visual-studio-2019, asp.net-core-3.1, http-status-code-500

I created my first REST API using asp.net core 3.1. It's very simple and has only one controller with two routes and talks to an SQL database (using Azure's DB). Everything works fine running it on localhost. I tried deploying it to Azure using Microsoft's own guides and various youtube videos. However, I always get a 500 Internal Server error. I'm publishing it straight from VS 2019. It says the Web App is started and ready.

I don't receive any error in the console log other than the 500.

I've tried changing the Configuration setting to 'Debug' instead of 'Release' on the Publish window, but it never hits any breakpoints.

I also hit the "Validate Connection" button on the Publish page, and it says the connection is fine.

Here's my `Program.cs`:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();

        var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

        using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
            try
            {
                var context = services.GetRequiredService<DataContext>();
                context.Database.Migrate();
                Seed.SeedScores(context);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
                logger.LogError(ex, "An error occured during migration");
            }
        }

        host.Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

Here's the `Startup.cs`:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") == "Production")
        {
            services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("LogansAppProd")));
        }
        else
        {
            services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(opt =>
            opt.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("LogansAppContextDev")));
        }

        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddCors();
        services.AddScoped<IScoreRepo, SqlScoreRepo>();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseCors("AllowAll");
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

And finally here's the controller (only showing one of the routes):

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ScoresController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IScoreRepo _repository;

    public ScoresController(IScoreRepo repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    //GET api/scores
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetScores()
    {
        var scoreItems = await _repository.GetAllScores();

        return Ok(scoreItems);
    }
}
```

Here's the project settings:
[image]

Here's the appsettings.json. The appsettings.Development.json is the same, just with a different connection string which I'm leaving out for security's sake:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "LogansAppContextProd": "Data Source=tcp:myserverhere.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=MyApp_db;User Id=idgoeshere@myappdbserver;Password=passwordgoeshere"
  }
}
```

Finally, here's the `launchSettings.json`:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:65278",
      "sslPort": 44321
    }
  },
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
      }
    },
    "LogansApp": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the publish window form vs 2019:
[image]

On Azure's page for the API, it does show all the 500 errors in the chart.
Not sure what else to try.

Comment: How did you deploy ? and do you have appinsights?

Comment: I deployed by right clicking on the project in visual studio and hitting publish. I updated the post with a screenshot of the publish window. Um I do not have appinsights, never heard of it before. Reading up on it now.

Comment: USE [Introduction to Remote Debugging on Azure Web Sites | Blog y actualizaciones de Azure | Microsoft Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/es-es/blog/introduction-to-remote-debugging-on-azure-web-sites/)

Comment: Navigate to your Web App blade and open Kudu console , see if your application is throwing any errso when starting up

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, there are few ways to see what is going on,

- You can use Use the KUDU console at **`https://yoursitename.scm.azurewebsites.net`** and see if its throwing any error when starting up
- Try adding [`Application Insights`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/monitor/) to the app. You should see errors on startup of your application.

Comment: Didn't see anything using the KUDU console (which I'm guessing is just the Log Stream at the top?). I'm unable to configure azure application  insights dependency in visual studio. I get this error: `NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.FatalProtocolException: Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. ---> System.TimeoutException: The HTTP request to 'GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json' has timed out after 100000ms.
   at NuGet.Protocol.TimeoutUtility.<StartWithTimeout>d__0`1.MoveNext()`

Comment: Am I supposed to be able to go to routes at the KUDU site? It says no route exists for the ones I have set up, but they do work locally.